# Seaborn objects facet without sharing y axis

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am attempting to create a faceted plot of overlays of three groups within my dataset, however the groups are on different scales so when faceted two of the plots are squashed. Is there a way of accessing the facet kws that I have missed? Using the classic API there is access to the `facet_kws` options to turn off sharing the y axis, but there does not seem to be a similar option through seaborn.objects. As I am trying to create faceted overlay plots, I would much prefer to stay within that environment.

Below is a snippet of my code to create the plot:

```
m_d111_subset
.pipe(
    lambda df: so.Plot(df, x="i")
    .facet('wavelength')
    .add(so.Line(), y="bcorr")
    .add(so.Dot(), y="peaks")
)
```

And the generated plot:

[a faceted plot with squashed groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHV7q.png)

Comment: Not what your question is directly about but note that you don't need the `lambda`, you can just pass `so.Plot` directly to `DataFrame.pipe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Plot.share](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.share.html), i.e.

```
so.Plot(...)
.share(y=False)
```